# How to enforce number of speakers in IBM Watson Speech to Text

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am using IBM Watson Speech to Text for transcription and diarization. I know that in my transcript, there are only 2 speakers. However, Watson assigned 3 unique speaker labels to my transcript.

Is there anyway to tell the model to only look for 2 speakers? I've come across other APIs that have a `num_speakers` parameter, but it doesn't look like IBM has one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the `speaker_labels` query parameter is a boolean, ie switch on or off only. https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text#recognize